GarageBand 2.3.16 (5293) skips the first note on the first playback of a section
I am using GarageBand on iPad with a hardware MIDI controller. I am having a problem that manifests in a similar way as well known early event issue (1, 2, 3) that affects all DAWs, where the MIDI event happens before the first bar, but it's clearly not what's happening here because on subsequent playbacks the first note plays correctly.
See this video on YouTube for a demo of what I am experiencing.
In the video I play 2 chords, at 0:04 and 0:06. When the section loops back, at 0:08 it should replay the first chord, but it doesn't. However, at 0:10 it correctly plays back the second chord. On subsequent loops, everything is good, which means that the first chord can be heard at 0:14, and the second at 0:16. Then, the first chord can be heard again at 0:18, and the second at 0:20. Finally, the first chord is heard one last time at 0:22 and the second at 0:24. After that I stopped the playback.
So it appears that the first playback of a newly recorded section is missing the first few notes. Then the problem auto-fixes itself.
Am I doing something wrong or maybe I stumbled into a bug?
Update 1.
I found someone that encountered a very similar behavior in Logic Pro.
Update 2. Another behavior, also affecting Logic Pro.

So have you tried the advice from the Logic forum? Can you rule out that you hit the note slightly before the first beat? Does the issue occur if you play the chords at 1& instead of 1?
